# Flutter SlideTransition with AnimatedList

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animatedlist

In the [Widget of the Week video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtfItHwFlZ8) they show the code to animate off an item like this:

```dart
AnimatedList(
  initialItemCount: _myItems.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: animation.drive(MyTween()),
      child: ...
    );
  }
)
```

I can't figure out how to configure `MyTween()` to show the child onscreen to start and then slide off screen later.

*I finally discovered the answer so I am sharing it below.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```dart
SlideTransition(
  position: animation.drive(myTween),
  child: Card(...),
)
```

where myTween is

```dart
final myTween = Tween<Offset>(
  begin: const Offset(-1.0, 0.0),
  end: Offset.zero,
);
```

Thanks to [this page](https://flutter-widget.live/widgets/AnimatedList) for help. See also my more general answer [here](https://medium.com/@suragch/updating-data-in-an-animatedlist-in-flutter-9dbfb136e515).